# Open text file from with JAR without extracting it - Help please

Tags: java, inputstream

I am trying to open a .txt file saved within a JAR and display its contents in a JTextArea.  Below is the code I am trying to use;

```
 URL urlToDictionary = this.getClass().getResource("eula/" + "eula.txt");
      try {
        InputStream stream = urlToDictionary.openStream();
        gettysburgTextStrBlder = stream;
        System.out.println(stream);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I know I am in the correct file location as I have changed the .getResource path around and seen null point exceptions, I have none with the current file path.

The System.out prints the following at runtime:

```
java.io.BufferedInputStream@3af42ad0
```

I have also tried;

```
gettysburgTextStrBlder = String.valueOf(stream);
```

But the result I get is the same.

I think I am nearly there, but am unsure how to get the actual content of the .txt file and not just the Buffered stream.

Thanks.

Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to read the content from the inputstream and display in the text area using [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

```
URL urlToDictionary = this.getClass().getResource("eula/" + "eula.txt");
  try {
    InputStream stream = urlToDictionary.openStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    String line = null;
    StringBuffer lineContent = new StringBuffer();
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        lineContent.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    br.close().
    System.out.println(lineContent.toString());
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I must be missing something else, in the line lineConent.add(line); eclipse is saying "The method add(String) is undefined for the type StringBuffer"

Comment: My mistake. it is `append` and not `add`. Corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks, works near perfectly.  Is there a way I can get the carriage returns detected out of the text file?  The JTextArea display the text all as a single line.

Comment: Just add a **new line character** `\n`. Updated the answer. Have a look.